# How can we restrict managed package not to installed by default in sandbox when refresh sandbox or created from production

Tags: sandbox, package, refresh

How can we restrict managed package not to installed by default  in sandbox when refresh sandbox or created from production .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The entire org's metadata is always copied (with a few special exceptions), so the only way to fix this is after creating/cloning the sandbox by uninstalling via CLI (e.g. SFDX) or manually.